# How to calculate id column day wise with total as well as unique ids in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
d = {'id': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A1', 'A2', 'A4', 'A1', 'A4', 'A5','A6', 'A2', 'A8'], 
     'date' : ['2021-02-01','2021-02-01','2021-02-01','2021-02-02','2021-02-02','2021-02-02','2021-02-03','2021-02-03','2021-02-03','2021-02-03','2021-02-04','2021-02-04']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Which I am trying to calculate unique as well as total ids daywise

My desired output is

```
d2 = {'total_count': [3, 3, 4, 2],
      'unique_count': [3, 1, 2, 1],
    'date' : ['2021-02-01','2021-02-02','2021-02-03','2021-02-04']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) for convert duplicates to `NaN`s and then use [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) for get number of non NaNs values with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for count all values:

```
df2 = (df1.assign(new = df1['id'].drop_duplicates())
          .groupby('date')
          .agg(total_count=('id','size'), 
               unique_count=('new','count')))
```

Similar alternative is use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with inverted mask and for count is used `sum`:

```
df2 = (df1.assign(new = ~df1['id'].duplicated())
          .groupby('date')
          .agg(total_count=('id','size'), 
               unique_count=('new','sum')))
print (df2)
            total_count  unique_count
date                                 
2021-02-01            3             3
2021-02-02            3             1
2021-02-03            4             2
2021-02-04            2             1
```